# Issues with some users in Win Authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I would like to get some help in my strange issues,
I have an ASP.Net 2.0 application with VB.NET Code behind,
I set up my application to enable only Win authentication
So in IIS all disabled except Windows auth,
In My Web.Config i have the following under system.web:

The Web.Config contains the following :

authentication mode="Windows"

```
     authorization>
         deny users="?"/>
     /authorization>
    identity impersonate="false"/>
```

Now some users when they enter to my ASP application they get prompted for user name and password , then they logged in successfully,
some users the application fails on Page.User.Identity.Name
and return Object Reference Error,

Im using VS2010 and ASP.NET 2.0 frameword 2.0 and IIS 7 under Win 2k8 R2 latest SP's installed.

All users are Domain users.

Thank you,

Comment: You should try to improve your formatting if you expect a solid answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the username by HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name? You can also check if authentication was successful, and what method of auth was used.

Windows authentication uses kerberos by default in iis I believe, which may not work for a lot of reasons (I think there are problems in Firefox for example ), when this fails, it is falling back to ntlm. Try removing the negotiate authentication provider and use just ntlm. If this works, you will have the fun of diagnosing kerberos problems :-)

Answer (score -1):

Trogvara,
Thank you for your posting ,
I'm new to the site and tried to formatted but it did what we see now,

the Web config setting is :

`<authentication mode="Windows"/>`
`<authorization>`
`<deny users="?"/>`
`<authorization/>`
`<identity impersonate="false"/>`

`<system.webServer>`
`<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>`
`</system.webServer>`

Hope that clears the setting in Web.config

Thank you,